# minimal graded projective resolution

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Suppose we are given a positively graded $k$ algebra $\bigoplus_{i\ge 0}A_i$ such that $A_0$ has finite global dimension. Furthermore all $A_i$ are finite dimensional and $A$ is generated in degree 0 and 1 i.e. $A_1A_i=A_{i+1}$.

Now the question:

Does every finitely generated graded $A$ module $M$ admit a minimal graded projective resolution 
$...\rightarrow P^{i+1}\rightarrow P^i\rightarrow ...\rightarrow P^0\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ such that $P^{i+1}$ is mapped to $A_+P^i$ for all $i$ ?

I know that this is true if $A_0$ is semisimple but I found nothing about what happens in the case where $A_0$ has finite global dimension.

I would be deeply grateful for any information or literature.

Comment: This does not work even in the case where A_1 is zero, so that A is concentrated in degree zero.

Comment: (If you redefine $A_+$ to be the sum of the things in positive degree and the Jacobson radical of $A_0$, on the other hand, you'll get essentially what you want. Straightforward changes to the usual proof should establish this; alternatively, the algebra is semi-perfect because this can be reduced immediately to the question of whether $A_0$ is semiperfect, which it is)

Comment: What do you mean exactely...We take $\tilde{A}=A_+\oplus rad(A_0)$ and we can establish a graded projective resolution such that $P^{i+1}$ is mapped to $\tilde{A}P^i$ ?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Where can I find this stuff on semi-perfect algabras? I even did not find the usual proof...:)

Comment: The proof of the usual case is done in one of Cartan's seminars; semi-perfect rings are treated in, say, Anderson-Fuller; that finite dimensional algebras are (semi-)perfect is proved in lots of places: it is a consequence of the fact that idempotents lift modulo the radical.

Comment: I propose you add an answer to this question with the results you gather. That way it will not remain unanswered.